# Get a date for a specific revision in Subversion

Tags: svn

So I have a repository that contains external repositories.  Using `svn log` on the repository URL gives me the output that contains the lines

```
Revision: 30584
...
Last Changed Rev: 30487
Last Changed Date: 2011-11-21 17:46:15 -0800 (Mon, 21 Nov 2011)
```

I am attempting to find what date revision 30584 (in this case) occurred on and whether or not it affected any of the internal repositories.

Other notes include that this repository that I am looking at is a "branch" of a main repository.

Answer (score 1):

To see the date use:

```
svn log -v -r 30487
```

Comment: This only works for the current repo that you are currently executing from but not any of the external repos unless your current directory is in that external repo :(

Comment: You can add the url or the repo `svn log -v -r 30487 ${url}` to get information about a remote repo.  I did not see you refer to a remote repo in your question and I did see "this repository" so I assumed you were wanting the information on a local repo.

Comment: Nope, that is exactly what I would be looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a "Compare", In Eclipse you have this option.

In that option you can see all the info that you need, number of revision, Last Chaned Rev, Author, etc.

To answer your question you need to give more information about SVN Server, IDE and Subversion application that you use.

Comment: This is using subversion from the command line and is an automated process so no IDE

Comment: This is using subversion application like Subeclipse and Ankhsvn. Or more simple, Tortoise can give you the files with differente version.